# Ruby Regular Expression match dimensions

Tags: ruby, regex, testing, web-scraping, nokogiri

Cirque Black Stone Effect Ceramic Floor Tile, Pack of 9, (L)333mm (W)333mm

I've created a block which iterates through a set of results i need to match the length (L)333mm and the width (W)333mm so I can add them to a database.

I've tried a few regular expressions but non of them are working now it feels like i'm just guessing.

`product_description = product.at_css('h3 a').text[/\L[0-9\.]+mm/]`

gives `nil`, can you please point me in the right direction

Comment: Try `\([LW]\)\d+mm`

Comment: @S.Kablar there's no capture group.

Comment: If you want to capture decimal numbers as well, then: `/\([LW]\)\d+(\.\d+)?mm/`, That matches one of `(L)` or `(W)`, followed by one or more digits, followed optionally by a decimal point and one or more digits, followed by `mm`.

Comment: Looks good - just here to add I always find [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) really handy for anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an out of order, len/width regex to get both in one pass.
Depends on conditionals, so this is if Ruby supports them.

The values are in the respective named groups.

**Edit**
For Ruby, out-of-order can be done like this.
Note that most engines let you reference a group before it is parsed.
With Ruby, you have to at least be inside at the start of the group
to be able to reference it's (current) contents.

`(?:\s*(?:\(W\)(?<width>(?(<width>)(?!))[\d.]+)(?<width_unit>[cm]?m|in|ft)|\(L\)(?<len>(?(<len>)(?!))[\d.]+)(?<len_unit>[cm]?m|in|ft))){1,2}`

http://rubular.com/r/SMw5bxHVYv

Formatted

```
 (?:
      \s* 
      (?:
           \(W\)
           (?<width>                     # (1 start), Width
                (?(<width>)                   # Conditional, cannot match width again
                     (?!)
                )
                [\d.]+ 
           )                             # (1 end)
           (?<width_unit> [cm]? m | in | ft )  # (2)
        |  \(L\)
           (?<len>                       # (3 start), Len
                (?(<len>)                     # Conditional, cannot match length again
                     (?!)
                )
                [\d.]+ 
           )                             # (3 end)
           (?<len_unit> [cm]? m | in | ft )  # (4)
      )
 ){1,2}    # Must match one or two
```

---

For other engines, you can put the conditional before the group definition.
(or at the start of the  group, as above)

`(?:\s*(?:(?(<width>)(?!))\(W\)(?<width>[\d.]+)(?<width_unit>[cm]?m|in|ft)|(?(<len>)(?!))\(L\)(?<len>[\d.]+)(?<len_unit>[cm]?m|in|ft))){1,2}`

https://regex101.com/r/VyCqjt/2

Formatted

```
 (?:
      \s* 
      (?:
           (?(<width>) (?!) )     # Conditional, cannot match width again
           \(W\)
           (?<width> [\d.]+ )                  # (1)
           (?<width_unit> [cm]? m | in | ft )  # (2)
        |
           (?(<len>) (?!) )        # Conditional, cannot match length again
           \(L\)
           (?<len> [\d.]+ )                 # (3)
           (?<len_unit> [cm]? m | in | ft ) # (4)
      )
 ){1,2}     # Must match one or two
```

Comment: Works exactly as I want within regex101.com doesn't however work with my ruby code.

Comment: Ok, even though Ruby supports conditionals, it is an outlier in that when it parses a regex it won't let an undefined group be referenced before it's parsed. So something like `(?(1)(?!))(group 1)` doesn't work because it is referenced in the conditional before it's actually parsed (defined). It's an outlier because almost every other engine supports this. Without this ability, you can't match out-of-order stuff like this. You have to match one or the other at a time. Sorry..

Comment: @JosephKouroma - Oh, wait. There is a way to fool it. Hang on .. http://rubular.com/r/SMw5bxHVYv

Comment: Thank you thats perfect. Im putting the details into a database, how about a regexp which puts only the numbers so in this case 9, 333, 333. {Cirque Black Stone Effect Ceramic Floor Tile, Pack of 9, (L)333mm (W)333mm}

Comment: @JosephKouroma - Yeah, just prepend `(?i)Pack\s*of\s*(?<PackOf>\d*)\s*,` to the regex above.